# Ignore phonetic guides when copying and pasting

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I have a bunch of furigana in my document. Whenever I want to copy a word or passage involving furigana and paste it outside of MS Word, like into Google Translate, the furigana shows up in brackets beside the word:

> 診断書(しんだんしょ)

Which forces me to highlight the bracketed part and remove it every time I want a plain, comprehensive passage. Is there any way to just exclude it from being copied?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy way to exclude it, here is a workaround:

- copy the whole text into a new document
- remove all brackets and everything between them:

  - press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
  - click `More` and check "use wildcards"
  - in "find what" type `\([!)]@\)`
  - leave "replace to" empty
  - click `Replace all`
- copy your text to the final destination